# My Code editor keeps saving/ storing my saves outside the working git repository

Tags: git, directory

I'm fairly unfamiliar with using github and recently stumpled upon this problem. I set up a git repository where I write my code, but whenever I save the file gets stored outside the repository, so unless I manually replace the file inside where I'm working I can't compile it. This is especially annoying when compiling, but I also have to do it for commiting the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Code Editor (VSCode? Visual Studio? other?): if that editor opens a files from the Git repository folder, it will save it at the same place.

So do a `git status` in your repo folder, and check those files are here.

Then try and launch your editor from the command line, passing as a parameter one of those files: modify it and double-check it is saved at its right place, within the Git repository.